# Synchronization problems with Meteor Collection's Helpers

Tags: mongodb, reactjs, meteor

I'm having the following error when trying to access a [collection helper](https://guide.meteor.com/collections.html#collection-helpers) from a collection:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined

My helper in /imports/api/.../TaskUser.js :

```
TaskUser.helpers({
  username() {
     Meteor.subscribe('users');
     elUser = Meteor.users.findOne({_id:this.userId})
     return (elUser.username)
}});
```

My component

```
renderResponsables(){
  return this.props.TaskUsers.map((OneTaskUser) => (
    <tr key= {resp._id} onClick={() => this.insert(OneTaskUser._id)}>
        <td>{OneTaskUser.username()}</td>
    </tr>
  ));
}
```

It look like sync problem... but how can I know when it's sync in the client? I usually use `subscription.ready()` but here with a helper I do not know how to do it.

Comment: (a) don't subscribe in a helper, do it in a `onCreated` handler in the parent template (b) show a loading spinner until the subscription is ready (c) only render the template when the subscription is ready.

Comment: i'm using REACT... so i think that a) and c) doesn't apply. I'll try to subscribe and wait in the react component.

Comment: Then you want to use `withTracker` inside a *container* to supply data to your *component* - see [docs](https://guide.meteor.com/react.html#using-withTracker)

Comment: Oh yes, i use it. The particularity in this case is that the data that returns withTracker have helpers associated with the scheme (https://guide.meteor.com/collections.html#collection-helpers). Those queries that are made in the helpers I thought were not automatically synchronized in the client, but now I think they do.

Answer (score 1):

**Advice1:**
First add below package

meteor add msavin:mongol

then run the program and press "ctrl+m" it will show you the database tables and your subscribed data.there you can whether that your data has been subscribed or not.

**Advice:2**
Place your subscribe inside the autorun in oncreated

```
Template.Dashboard.onCreated(function(){
   var self = this;
   self.subscribe('users');
});
```

if above dosn't work then I need to check your users table how you created that and how you retrieve data from there correctly

Answer (score 0):

Did you check this https://guide.meteor.com/react.html#data. You should use `react-meteor-data` package which provides a function called `withTracker`. Your subscription should go into it and you have to wrap your component with a container to pass the data.

Comment: As i said, yes, i use withTracker. The particularity in this case is that the data that returns withTracker have helpers associated with the scheme (guide.meteor.com/collections.html#collection-helpers). Those queries that are made in the helpers I thought were not automatically synchronized in the client, but now I think they do.